# Calling Oracle PL/SQL stored procedure from java middle tier using JDBC on Linux?

Tags: jdbc, plsql

Newbie question... Can anyone provide a high level description of what things need to be done in a PL/SQL stored procedure (residing in a database Linux server) to send data to a Java program (in an application server)?

UPDATE 1

elrado's answer below moved me forward (thanks!). I can see that the PL/SQL stored procedure simply needs to set an OUT parameter as REF CURSOR (e.g. SYS_REFCURSOR). Then, the calling Java routine can use something like this:

```java
import oracle.jdbc.*;
...
// call stored procedure using SQL92 syntax
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall( "{call myStoredProc (?,?,?,?,?)}" );

// set IN parameters
cs.setString(1, in1var);
cs.setString(2, in2var);
cs.setString(3, in3var);

// register OUT parameters
cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
cs.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

// execute and retrieve Oracle "ref cursor" as a Java "ResultSet"
cs.execute();
rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(5);

// process result
while (rs.next()) {
  ...
}

// always retrieve ResultSet before OUT parameters
out1var = cs.getInt(4);
```

QUESTION 1: Does the above look OK?

I see in Oracle's documentation (see pages 4-14 to 4-15 http://isu.ifmo.ru/docs/doc112/java.112/e10589.pdf) that I should use an `OracleCallableStatement` instead of a `CallableStatement` so that it should look like this:

```java
// execute and retrieve Oracle "ref cursor" as a Java "ResultSet"
cs.execute();
rs = {(OracleCallableStatement)cs}.getCursor(5);
```

QUESTION 2: Are both methods fine? If so, what are the pro's and con's for using one over the other?

QUESTION 3: I didn't understand the `Important` note on page 4-15 regarding Oracle 11G database:

`Unlike in past releases, the cursor associated with a REF CURSOR is not closed when the result set object in which the REF CURSOR was materialized is closed.`

Does this mean that the `ref cursor` is closed when `cs` is closed (as opposed to previous database releases, which closed `ref cursor` when `rs` is closed)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return resultset from Oralce PL/SQL procedure use ref cursor:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/UsingRefCursorsToReturnRecordsets.php

**Q1:** Yes it LOOKS ok but I had not tested it.
**Q2:**
I belive OracleCallableStatement just extends CallableStatement. Both are fine but when ever possible I am using Oracle driver to connect and work with Oracle db (and not some generic driver).

**Q3:I belive you're right and cursor stays open when you close resultset.** (It has been some time since I read resultset from procedure so I don't remember when I closed cursor sorry. And right now I am at home and don't have access to Oracle db and my work computer.)

Comment: Thanks elrado. It's confusing. Some examples, like your link above, use the `execute()` statement, with OracleCallableStatement and getCursor. Other links don't use `ref cursor`, but use the `executeQuery()` statement, with CallableStatement (see last section in this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html#calling_javadb_mysql as well as: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/StoredprocedurewithInputOutputparmsandaResultSet.htm). And still other examples use `ref cursor` with `executeQuery()` statement, with CallableStatement and getObject().

Comment: @ggkmath what did you come up with :).

Comment: Hi elrado, I tried it for the first time just now and it's working fine. Thanks to your hint about ref cursor above, I was able to make this progress. Thanks for taking the time to submit an answer! It really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If your database framework is `spring-jdbc`, you can try to use [morejdbc](https://github.com/seregamorph/morejdbc) (available in maven central). The call will look like

```java
import static org.morejdbc.NamedJdbcCall.call;
import static org.morejdbc.SqlTypes.*;
import org.morejdbc.*;

...
// note: it can be either INTEGER or VARCHAR - you declare one type, but get result via another
Out<Integer> out4 = Out.of(INTEGER);
// you did not declare the structure of cursor result set, so assume it's a single column of VARCHAR
Out<List<String>> out5 = OracleSqlTypes.cursor((rs, rowNum) -> rs.getString(1));

// named parameter binding is used, hence argument declaration order can be any
jdbcTemplate.execute(call("myStoredProc")
        .in("in1", in1var)) // note: first argument is pl/sql parameter name
        .in("in2", in2var)
        .in("in3", in3var)
        .out("out4", out4)
        .out("out5", out5)); // will close REF_CURSOR automatically

System.out.println("out4 is " + out4.get());
System.out.println("out5 is " + out5.get());
```

Q2: I've checked on docker image `wnameless/oracle-xe-11g-r2` with driver `11.2.0.4`, both order of OUT parameter retrieval is fine.