# Why won't this stored procedure call from Java work?

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, plsql, call

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VIEWBROKERS 
(o_username OUT USERS.USERNAME%TYPE) 

AS 
BEGIN
 SELECT USERNAME
 INTO o_username
 FROM USERS
WHERE Role_ID = 3 ;

END VIEWBROKERS;
```

Here is my method calling the stored procedure:

```
public ResultSet pullBrokers() {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(Messages.getString("OracleUserManagement.0"), Messages.getString("OracleUserManagement.1"), Messages.getString("OracleUserManagement.2")); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$

        String storedProcedure = "{call VIEWBROKERS(?)}"; 
    CallableStatement statement = con.prepareCall(storedProcedure);

    statement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    rs = statement.executeQuery();

    con.commit();
    con.close();

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return rs;
}
```

And lastly when I tried to print out the results:

```
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
        OraclePullListOfUsers pull = new OraclePullListOfUsers();

        ResultSet rs = pull.pullBrokers();
        try {
            while (rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

I get the error message ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Which is strange ,because there are only two rows of data in the table...

If someone could point me in the right the direction, that would be awesome!

Comment: How many rows does your select statement return? If it returns more than 1, that's where your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're problem is not related to Java, just on the SQL side. Could it be that both those two rows in the table have Role_ID=3?

Comment: Yes there are two rows which have Role_ID=3.

The point is that I want it to return multiple rows!

Comment: Also, even if there is one row, I still get an error:

"Closed Connection: next"

Comment: @oOTesterOo You can only have a singleton result when using `OUT` parameters AFAIK. So having more than one result is the problem.

Comment: Ok well thanks for the help anyway.

I guess using a stored procedure for this command isn't the way to go

Answer (score 1):

The root cause for your problem:

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

is that PL/SQL [`select into` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm) expects a query to match to exactly one row. If the query returns no rows or if the query return more than one row (as in your case) it will throw an exception.

You can't use `select into` to save the results to a single `out` variable if the query can return more than one row. Instead your subprogram should return a cursor (that is a pointer to a record set) that your Java component can query. Note that returning a cursor is not the only option, but in your case it looks like a good starting point.

This issue has been addressed several times in StackExchange universe. Please take a look e.g.

- [Return many rows on a plsql Oracle10g](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18256/6260)
- [How to return multiple rows from the stored procedure? (Oracle PL/SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/101033/272735)
- [Calling Oracle PL/SQL stored procedure from java middle tier using JDBC on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549399/272735)

A Java example [Using Ref Cursors To Return Recordsets](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php).