# stored procedure for select query not giving output

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, sqlplus, procedure

I am using `sqlplus` and have a table named `users` from which I wish to retrieve all values with the help of a `stored procedure` in `oracle`. Here is what I am trying to do -

```
create or replace procedure getall(prc out sys_refcursor)
is
begin
open prc for select * from users
end;
/
```

When I hit `return` after this, I get the following error -

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

Why does this happen? And how do I get the desired output? Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the compilation errors use [the `show errors‌​` SQL*Plus command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve041.htm) (which also works in SQL Developer), or query the `user_errors` view which works with any client. You can also query `all_errors` to see problems with objects that are not in your schema.

But you are just missing a semicolon after the select:

```
create or replace procedure getall(prc out sys_refcursor)
is
begin
  open prc for select * from users;
end;
/
```

You'll need a bind variable to be able to see the output in SQL*Plus, e.g.:

```
variable rc refcursor;
exec getall(:rc);
print rc
```

Notice the colon before the `rc` in the procedure call, which shows it's a bind variable reference. And [`exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm) is a shorthand anonymous block.

You might find it simpler to have a function that returns a ref cursor, or a pipelined function; or just query the table directly of course.

Comment: thanks that helped alot. Do you know how I can call the same within a java class and get the response there as well? Many thanks @AlexPoole

Comment: @VidhiSinha - there's an example [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9549399/266304). The answer to that also links to [an article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets) with a full Java example. It's fairly straightforward but if you can't get it working you should ask a new question showing your Java code.

Comment: thanks bruh, will get back to you on this @Alex Poole